# Read into multiple .csv files

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to read into `csv.` files from a specific location. How do I read multiple files into the global environment at once?
How do I unpack the contents of a list of data frames into it, or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the data in a list.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = 'csv$', full.names = TRUE)
list_data <- lapply(filenames, readr::read_csv)
```

It is not recommended to create multiple objects in global environment (like `df1`, `df2` etc) because they are difficult to manage but if you need them you can use `list2env`

```
names(list_data) <- paste0('df', seq_along(list_data))
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thanks i learned something about new- i updated my question basically I don't want to read into my data - I just want a file with the read_csv command.

Comment: Do you mean instead of using `list.files` you want to read specific files? Maybe using `filenames <- paste0(1:10, '.csv')` would work if those files are in working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question properly, does this work?

```
tables_to_read <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
     tables_to_read[i] <- read_csv(paste0(i, '.csv'))
 }
```

Comment: thanks but how can I read into the 10 df with df1 ...df10 names respectively